# Make Audio Capture Engine (ACE) to act as an Input Device for Quicktime Screen Recording

Tags: audio, screen-capture, quicktime, microphone

so currently I am running macOS Ventura 13.1 on MacBook Air M1 model. For Discord, I managed to download Rogue Amoeba's *Audio Capture Engine (ACE)* for screen share audio.

I am interested in knowing is there a way for me to establish an aggregate device on Audio MIDI Setup so that I can utilise both the ACE and my microphone (if need be)? At the moment, my recognised audio devices do not showcase the ACE plugin.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, ACE needs to be called specifically by any app that uses it. It doesn't ordinarily appear as an audio device itself. Rogue Amoeba licence their technology to other companies so they can use it in their own structures.

[Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) uses the same technology to insert itself into any point on the audio path. [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/) provides a way to expose inputs & outputs to the system itself, so they can be used for inter-application routing, Aggregate & Multi-Output Devices.
Both the Rogue Amoeba apps have free trials, so you could test.

There's a freeware alternative to Loopback [which I've never tested personally] called [Black Hole](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole), that seems to be able to do a similar thing. I have no idea whether this can integrate both ACE & non-ACE audio paths.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll probably use Black Hole in the mean time, but I am quite intrigued of trying to develop some app that utilises ACE and try a way to expose the inputs/outputs to the system as you implied.

Comment: Presumably the API is available to developers wanting to subscribe to their system [I have no idea how their business model works, sorry], but Loopback already does what you're considering.